# how to compare two hash maps?

Tags: java

How to compare the values in both hash maps with the help of keys ? Since the keys are identical whereas values are'nt.
and return boolean result for each key comparision.
like:

```
map1=[1,res]
[2,tr]
[3,677]
[4,cv]  

map2=[1,res]
[2,cd]
[3,677]
[4,fs]
```

It should return me

```
true
false
true
false
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post what you have tried so far

Comment: As maps are in general not "ordered," you will need to return the key along with the boolean -- otherwise you will not be able to tell what boolean refers to what key...

Answer (score 9):

Here's a method that generates a Map of the results (Map of key to boolean). It will play nicely regardless of different keys and key sort order:

```
/**
 * Works with any two maps with common key / value types.
 * The key type must implement Comparable though (for sorting).
 * Returns a map containing all keys that appear in either of the supplied maps.
 * The values will be true if and only if either
 *   - map1.get(key)==map2.get(key) (values may be null) or
 *   - map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key)).
 */
public static <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
Map<K, Boolean> compareEntries(final Map<K, V> map1,
    final Map<K, V> map2){
    final Collection<K> allKeys = new HashSet<K>();
    allKeys.addAll(map1.keySet());
    allKeys.addAll(map2.keySet());
    final Map<K, Boolean> result = new TreeMap<K, Boolean>();
    for(final K key : allKeys){
        result.put(key,
            map1.containsKey(key) == map2.containsKey(key) &&
            Boolean.valueOf(equal(map1.get(key), map2.get(key))));
    }
    return result;
}

private static boolean equal(final Object obj1, final Object obj2){
    return obj1 == obj2 || (obj1 != null && obj1.equals(obj2));
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    final Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map1.put(1, null);
    map1.put(2, "Different");
    map1.put(3, "Same");
    map1.put(4, "First Map only");
    final Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map2.put(3, "Same");
    map2.put(1, null);
    map2.put(2, "Yup, different");
    map2.put(5, "Second Map only");
    final Map<Integer, Boolean> comparisonResult =
        compareEntries(map1, map2);
    for(final Entry<Integer, Boolean> entry : comparisonResult.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Entry:" + entry.getKey() + ", value: "
            + entry.getValue());
    }

}
```

Output:

> Entry:1, value: true
>   Entry:2, value: false
>   Entry:3, value: true
>   Entry:4, value: false
>   Entry:5, value: false

Answer (score 5):

I was directed here from [this (possibly duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586897/java-compare-two-map) and was surprised to find that [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html) wasn't mentioned in the answers.

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, use the handy the [`Maps.difference`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference%28java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map%29) method.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have the same entry sets:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class HashMapComparison {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map1.put(1, "res");
        map1.put(2, "tr");

        HashMap<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map2.put(1, "res");
        map2.put(2, "cd");

        for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            System.out.println("key " + key + ": "
                    + entry.getValue().equals(map2.get(key)));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'd turn this around: `map2.get(key).equals(entry.getValue()))` otherwise you get NullPointerExceptions if `map2.get(key)` is null

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I changed it, but as I already said in the answer I was assuming that the entry sets are the same, i.e. are containing the same elements.

Comment: not a good answer as although you mention that you assume that the entry sets are the same - you can't be sure about it

Answer (score 2):

You can take keys of one map (with [keySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) method), iterate through them, get values from both maps (with [get()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method), and compare them.

Also, you can use [values()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) method to get all key-value pairs form one map, iterate through it and compare values with values from another map.

Comment: This will only work if the keySets are sorted, so you will have to wrap the sets in `new TreeSet(keySet)` calls.

Comment: Sean Patrick Floyd - I meant, call get(key) method for each map. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo Code:

```
HashMap map1;
HashMap map2;
HashMap resultMap;
for(KeyType key : map1.keySet() ) {
  if(map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key)){
    resultMap.put(key,true);
  } else {
    resultMap.put(key,false);
  }
```

}

Comment: Nice (+1) but it doesn't deal with maps with different keys

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I'm going through Cracking the Coding Interview and wanted to compare hash maps to solve the problem of checking whether two words are anagrams (without sorting). You just have to do the check in both directions, i.e. if the key-value pair set of map1 is a subset of map2, and similarly map2 is a subset of a map1, then they're the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("AA","aaa");
map.put("BB","bbb");
map.put("CC","ccc");
map.put("DD","ddd");

Map map2 = new HashMap();
map2.put("BB","bbb");
map2.put("AA","aaa");
map2.put("DD","ddd");
map2.put("CC","ccc");

if(map.equals(map2))
{
    System.out.println("Eql");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
mapA.equals(mapB);
```

This will give back a boolean result.